# How do I get my JSON data to show up on the page?

Tags: angularjs, json, api

I'm using an API to make a table of all the data. The JSON url is connected (which I verified with a 200 Status). What am I doing wrong? Most importantly, if there is another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, I'm open.

```js
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("RacingApp", []);
    app.controller("DriversCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/driverStandings.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK").then(function(response) {
            $scope.driver = response.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings;
        });
    });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>F1 Racing API</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body ng-app="RacingApp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="DriversCtrl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-compressed">
                    <thead id="table-header">
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="5">
                                <div class="text-left col-md-6">Drivers Championship Standings</div>
                                <div class="text-right col-md-6">
                                
                                </div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Place</th>
                            <th>Nationality</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Sponsor</th>
                            <th>Points</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="info in information">
                            <th scope="row">{{$index + 1}}</th>
                            <td>{{info.Driver.nationality}}</td>
                            <td><a href="Driver's Wikipedia Page">{{info.Driver.givenName}} &amp; {{info.Driver.familyName}}</a></td>
                            <td><a href="Sponsor's Wikipedia Page">{{info.Constructors[0].name}}</a></td>
                            <td>{{info.points}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how many questions you have added for the same purpose?

Comment: None. The question I'm asking is purely situational. One thing may not work for the other.

Answer (score 0):

I found a resolution. For whatever reason, the package I received back from the server was MRData.data, which didn't show up in the actual JSON data. It works now!!